# How to filter category and subcategory

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with filtering the category and subcategory results that I display in an html table as a nested set. The table category contains `parent_id' with relation` hasMany'. I successfully filter the parent categories, but I can't achieve filtering from the same html input field for the subcategories.

Check my code belowe

**Category model**

```
 public function children()
 {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
 }
```

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $stores = Store::all();
    $categories = Category::with(['store','children'])->whereNull('parent_id')
        
        ->when($request->has('name'), function ($q) use($request) {
            return $q->where('name', 'like', $request->query('name') .'%');
        })
        
        ->when($request->query('store') , function ($q) use($request) {
            return $q->where('store_id', $request->query('store'));
        })

       // This not work

        ->whereHas('children' , function ($q) use($request) {
            return $q->where('name', 'like', $request->query('name') .'%');
        })

       // This not work

        ->when($request->query('name') , function ($q) use($request) {
            return $q->whereHas('children', function ($cq) use($request) {
                return $cq->where('name', $request->query('name'));
            });
        })

       // Also this try not working

       ->with(['children', function ($q) use($request) {
            return $q->where('name', 'like', $request->query('name') .'%');
        }])

        ->paginate(20);

    return view('ecommerce::admin.catalog.category.index', compact('categories', 'stores'));
}
```

**Blade**

```
<tbody>
@forelse($categories as $category)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
    </tr>
    @if(count($category->children))
        @foreach($category->children as $child)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $child->name }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@empty
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8" class="text-center">{{ __('No records.') }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforelse
</tbody>
```

I have one html text input box from which I want to filter all the categories in the table. And I think the problem is in `@foreach($category->children as $child)` because it doesn't recognize the `children` collection

Anyone can suggest me solution to slove this? Thanks!